# Maintaining Squad Cohesion

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been playing the campaign mode using Raptor Speedlings, and they end up crossing the map far faster than any other units at my disposal, which can lead to some problems.

In many games, selecting a large group of units and giving them a move command together slows down the faster units to the pace of the slower, allowing the army to arrive at an objective together. Is there a way to enable this (either click mechanism or a setting) in Starcraft 2?

I know that this flies in the face of using Speedlings, but I often find it useful to send about half a dozen ahead to scout, while keeping the rest with my army to defend my roaches, hydras, Kerrigan, etc. As it is I have to give commands to the rest of the units, and follow them in short jumps with the lings, which reduces my ability to manage my base as effectively during maneuvers.

Comment: You can set your units to follow other units, so you can set your zerglings to follow Kerrigan and they will stay with Kerrigan when you move here group

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

There are no formations in Starcraft 2. If you want to keep your squad together, make a series of smaller move commands instead of a small amount of large moves. If you want to "set and forget" an army move command, then you will have to accept the consequences that they will split up. Keep an eye on the map for hostile units that try to intercept your army.

Units that have special needs (like zerglings, casters, etc) should be in their own control group and given special move commands. For example while battling the enemy, zerglings do better when told to run past the enemy and then attack so they can get a better surround - while ranged units like roaches are fine when being told to attack + move into an enemy army. Other situations like the "protoss death ball" require the army to behave in a certain manner - such as keeping colossi in the middle of the army. This eliminates the need for any kind of "move together" command that other games have, as it is a bad habit to form anyways.

Answer (score 3):

No.

As Resorath has mentioned there are many reasons not to want this, but there are ways to get around it somewhat.

All units can be set to follow other units by right clicking*, so you can set your faster units to follow your slower units and then move with a group only containing your slow units.

If your units stop, either because you have [A-moved](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15397/in-starcraft-what-is-an-a-move) or they reached their destination, the units that are set to follow will attack any hostile in their range.

The only downside is your slow units will always be in front when moving ahead and the units following will not have as fast reaction time on starting an attack as if they were set to A move.

*With units that can transport (most noticeably the medivac) you will need to select the [scan move](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64723/what-is-scan-move) to follow because the right click command on another unit is not "follow" but "pick up target".

Answer (score 1):

**No but you can try to make it happen**! ;)

**Click** on speedlings **pressing Shift** (this make you able to give more than one command) with **Ctrl** (this will select only the type of unit you clicked) and make **special longer route** only for them maintaining the shortest one for your main army.